# zoho creator get records from zoho project

Tags: task, projects, zoho

I am using zoho creator and I need to fetch records from zoho projects using api ( like zoho.books.getRecords(...) ) to liste all tasks.

I need somtjing like this :

```
response1 = zoho.books.getRecords("Invoices",organization_id,"cf_no_de_projet=" + no_projet);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This URL lists all projects in a portal (JSON):

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/<PORTAL_ID>/projects/?authtoken=<YOUR_AUTHTOKEN>
```

*You can run a GET request in Creator with the same parameters.*

If you don't know the *Portal ID*, you can get a list of all available portals:

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portals?authtoken=<YOUR_AUTHTOKEN>
```

Comment: How can I find my authtoken in Zoho Creator? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Internal API for ZOHO Project. you must be used External API.
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal//projects/?authtoken=

Comment: How can I find my authtoken in Zoho Creator? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi, Please go to Account Setup->Extension->Connection->select Zoho Auth-> Select All Zoho Project Scope->used that Connection name in Invoke URL as connection name.
-
https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/webhook/invokeurl-api-task.html

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me with this issue? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076554/how-to-export-data-from-zoho-expense-site-to-power-bi-desktop-using-the-zoho-cre