# How to export data from Zoho Expense site to Power BI desktop using the Zoho Creator (Beta) app

Tags: powerbi, zoho, powerbi-datasource, zohobooks

I need to **export** data from **Zoho Expense site** to **Power BI desktop** using the Zoho Creator (Beta) app
Is that possible? Please let know
Also, how can I find the domain, the workspace name, the Application link name and the Report name link
as you can see in the Screenshot:
[image]

And how to get the Authotoken from the Zoho Creator account as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

If this method doesn't work, please let me know about other methods.
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Login ur Creator Account & https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/create?SCOPE=ZohoCreator/creatorapi using this URL create Creator Auth Token.

Note: Make sure ur domain code is correct.

Workspace:
https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/account-settings/workspace.html

Simple Access ur creator account & on URL will get all details
https://creatorapp.zoho.eu/ownername/appname/#Report or #form :linkname